# Log4Net RollingFileAppender not giving Custom property in Win8/VS2013

Tags: c#, windows-8, log4net

I am creating a custom property in Log4Net with Visual Studio 2010 on Win7 and it is able to create everything well with the correct property. But If i try to run the same program on Win8 and Visual Studio 2013, it do create the log file but without the custom property.

I have not edited anything and same thing is working in WIn7 but not in Win8.

I don't know what is changing in both of these environments. Can anyone give hint at what to look for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
  <appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\TSAS_DRU_Log\%property{LogName}" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="TSAS_DRU_app.CsvPatternLayout, TSAS_DRU_app">
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CsvFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
  </configuration>
```

Update: I am setting the property in the code as following which is working correctly in WIn7 but not in Win8 where I have just updated the Visual studio as version 2013 with 2010:

```
string LogName = "TSAS_DRU_Log_" + date + ".csv";
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = LogName;
```

Comment: How are you setting the property?

Comment: Updated the question with how I am setting the property.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its solved finally and the issue was with the regional settings of the Win8 machine which was causing the date format to change and thus the complete name of the logfile with the static part and the date was not coming.

Thanks to log4net log files it got solved and also thanks to Psenner who is one of the handler of the log4net for giving insights.